# Políticas de cookies jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Estoy intentando poner las políticas de cookies en mi web pero no funciona correctamente. He probado dos variantes y ninguna de las dos me funciona correctamente.

```js
function GetCookie(name) {
    var arg=name+"=";
    var alen=arg.length;
    var clen=document.cookie.length;
    var i=0;
    while (i<clen) {
        var j=i+alen;
 
        if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
            return "1";
        i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
        if (i==0)
             break;
     }
    return null;
}
 
function aceptar_cookies(){
    var expire=new Date();
    expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
    document.cookie="cookies_surestao=aceptada; expires="+expire;
 
    var visit=GetCookie("cookies_surestao");
    if (visit==1){
        popbox3();
    }
}
 
jQuery(function() {
    var visit=GetCookie("cookies_surestao");
    if (visit==1){
        $('#overbox3').toggle();
    } else {
        var expire=new Date();
        expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
        document.cookie="cookies_surestao=aceptada; expires="+expire;
    }
});
 
function popbox3() {
    $('#overbox3').toggle();
}
```

```css
#overbox3 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    display: block;
}
#infobox3 {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#infobox3 p {
    line-height:58px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
}
#infobox3 p a {
    margin-right:5px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="overbox3">
    <div id="infobox3">
        <p>Esta web utiliza cookies para obtener datos estadísticos de la navegación de sus usuarios. Si continúas navegando consideramos que aceptas su uso.
        <a href="politica-privacidad.php">Más información</a>
        <a onclick="aceptar_cookies();" style="cursor:pointer;">X Cerrar</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como se puede ver da un error (que en mi servidor local ni siquiera sale) al aceptarlas no se cierra el div que lo contiene
Por otra parte he probado de hacerlo así:

```js
function getCookie(c_name){
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1){
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1){
        c_value = null;
    }else{
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1){
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
 
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
 
if(getCookie('tiendaaviso')!="1"){
    document.getElementById("barraaceptacion").style.display="block";
}
function PonerCookie(){
    setCookie('tiendaaviso','1',365);
    document.getElementById("barraaceptacion").style.display="none";
}
```

```css
#barraaceptacion {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999;
}
 
.inner {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    top:30%;
}
 
.inner a.ok {
    padding:4px;
    color:#00ff2e;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.inner a.info {
    padding-left:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#faff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="barraaceptacion" style="display: block;">
    <div class="inner">
        Solicitamos su permiso para obtener datos estadísticos de su navegación en esta web, en cumplimiento del Real 
        Decreto-ley 13/2012. Si continúa navegando consideramos que acepta el uso de cookies.
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="PonerCookie();"><b>OK</b></a> | 
        <a href="http://politicadecookies.com" target="_blank" class="info">Más información</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

También sale el mismo error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De usar algo parecido a lo tuyo, yo usaría [estos códigos que son open source](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/) lo mismo ([en Github](https://github.com/insites/cookieconsent)) y tienen varias opciones disponibles que según el sitio web que sea puedes poner el consentimiento de cookies en una lugar o en otro. Y con esto ya sabes que funciona seguro. No es una solución a tu problema por lo que soy consciente de que te estoy ayudando pero no a resolver lo que ya has hecho programando, que es mucho. Pero es una solución a este problema tan frecuente del tema de las cookies. Una solución que puede servir para todos.

Quizás esto es más un comentario que una respuesta.
He tratado de que fuera una respuesta para todos.